# How to retrieve value from Singleton object via generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am trying to create a function that can take any singleton object in, and print it's properties with values.

Sample code:

```
object MyObject {
    val text = "Hello World"
}

inline fun <reified T: Any> printValues() = T::class
    .declaredMemberProperties
    .forEach {
        println(it.name + "=" + it.value) // value doesn't exist
    }


/* RUN */
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    printValues<MyObject>()
}
```

Is it possible in kotlin to retrieve the value from MyObject in some generic way like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> getObjectValues() = T::class
    .declaredMemberProperties
    .map { it.name to it.get(T::class.objectInstance!!) }
```

Basically what you need is to obtain an instance of T so that you can call `get`